Incremental repair failed with IOException: "Endpoint /x.x.x.x died"
In Cassandra 3.11 cluster, initiated a incremental repair from one of the nodes in the cluster. The repair got stuck while the tpstats shows the repair task as completed. I see the below logs on that initiated node.
ERROR [GossipTasks:1] 2024-05-31 08:33:02,462 RepairSession.java:338 - [repair #120652d0-1d9d-11ef-b103-832d9c825070] session completed with the following error
java.io.IOException: Endpoint /x.x.x.x died
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.convict(RepairSession.java:337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.FailureDetector.interpret(FailureDetector.java:307)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doStatusCheck(Gossiper.java:802)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.access$700(Gossiper.java:68)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$GossipTask.run(Gossiper.java:194)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

We are either facing the validation failed or endpoint died issue during an incremental repair which is hindering the repair percent. Could you please help us with a possible solution/root cause for this issue

The error message you posted simply indicates that the repair session completed with errors on another replica.
You need to check the logs on the other replica, specifically for repair messages relating to session ID #120652d0-1d9d-11ef-b103-832d9c825070, since those log entries will provide a clue as to why the repair session failed. Cheers!
